# Intuition behind the Formula for an estimator

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

An estimator for a set of i.i.d samples drawn from a Gaussian distribution can be

$ \sigma^{2}_{m} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} (x^{(i)} - \mu_{m})^{2}$

this is called the sample variance and $\mu_{m} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} x^{i} $ is the sample mean. As $x^{(i)}$ is a random variable (a sample drawn from the Gaussian distribution), how do we proceed to calculate $\sigma_{m}^{2}$? if $x^{(i)}$ were data points, it would have been obvious but this is not the case here. Should we calculate $\sigma_{i}^{2}$ for $i=1,..,m$ for each sample $x^{(i)}$ and then sum them over?

Comment: A random sample of length $m, m \in \mathbb{N}$ is a set of realizations of $m$ independent, identically distributed (iid) random variables with distribution F: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics) Hence, sample consists of observations and not of random variables. Sample variance is calcualted based on the observations as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance  What exactly does your notation $x^{(i)}$ mean?

Comment: My source is Goodfellow's book (Introduction to deep learning). According to him: ${x^{1}, ... , x^{(m)}}$ are a set of samples that are independently and identically distributed according to a (let's say Gaussian) distribution $p(x^{(i)}) = N(x^{(i)}; \mu, \sigma^{2})$

Comment: I have only access to this book https://www.deeplearningbook.org/, but there in the notation (page xvi) it is said: $x^{(i)}$ The $i$-th example (input) from a dataset. So I guess they have in mind the observations, or real data points. Do you then maybe have $\mu_n = \frac{1}{m}\sum x^{(i)}$ as well? I would say it is a little uncommon notation from the point of statistical literature, but I guess in the machine learning literature it can be different.

Comment: I am referring to the page 125, Example: Gaussian Distribution Estimator of the Mean.

Comment: The notation is used consistently throughout the book. On page 123 the sample mean is also defined with the help of $x^{(i)}$, which is consistent with what I was telling about regarding $x^{(i)}$: it is a single observation. Moreover, on page 120 they say "let $\{x^{(1)}, \ldots, x^{(m)}\}$ be a set of $m$ independent and identically distributed data points" and they they define statistic based on this. What I am trying to say is that: an estimator or statistic is constructed based on the data you have. Personally I think that "a set of samples" is not used correctly here.

Comment: Thank you. What confuses me is that they have a derivation (equations 5.31 to 5.35) and there $E[x^{(i)}]$ is equal to $\mu$. If $x^{(i)}$ is only an observation then how should I justify this. This derivation is part of calculating the bias of the sample mean estimator.

Comment: To be honest, I do not think that this book is very good in all of these mathematical nuances. I would write $E[X_i]$ or even $E[X]$ since all is iid. Maybe this answer can help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/396949/324942. In brief, if you are interested in just an estimator for the data that you already have, then $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is just a number calculated from the observations, but if you would like to know the general properties of an estimator (like expectation, bias, asymptotic properties), then you should regard it as a function of random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited after reading comments below to avoid making two answers.

Consider $X_1, X_2,...,X_m$ an iid random sample.
Let $x_1, x_2,...,x_m$ a realization from $X_1, X_2,...,X_m$. Then $x_1, x_2,...,x_m$ are actual numbers. Since $X_1, X_2,...,X_m$ are iid, we can think of $x_1, x_2,...,x_m$ as m realizations of one stochastic variable $X$ which is iid. with $X_1, X_2,...,X_m$ (or just $X_1$).

$\sigma^2_m=\sigma^2_m(X_1,X_2,...,X_m)$ as described above is called an estimator. The notation with $m$ is because $\sigma^2_m$ depends on the sample size. The stochastic variables $X_1, X_2,...,X_m$ are often suppressed in the notation.

In practice we cannot calculate $\sigma^2_m$ before we have an actual sample $x_1,..,x_m$ of known values. We call $\hat{\sigma^2_m}= \sigma^2_m(x_1,x_2,...,x_m)$ the estimate of $\sigma^2_m$.

For each sample there is one variance estimate, and one mean estimate.

I hope this helps with the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, what you mean is we calculate the estimate for just one random variable? doesn't it violate the definition above. I also need to mention that $\sigma_{m}^{2}$ is actually $\^\sigma_{m}^{2}$

Comment: It is sigma hat. I am not able to write it down correctly. My apologies.

Comment: Yes and no. $X_1, X_2,...,X_m$ are each one random variable, however they are i.i.d. so you can think of $x_1,...,x_m$ as $m$ realizations of one random variable, $X$ , that is identical distributed with $X_1$.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think I get it.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer above to incorporate the comments. I hope it improves the answer.